# SwiftのWebKitで検索した際に画像が表示されない問題

Tags: swift, macos, google-chrome, 画像

### Current status

- 自分用に単純なMacOSアプリを開発しています。
- 仕様としてはWebKitで人気のあるレシピを検索するだけのものです(下記コード参照) 。

  ```
  import Cocoa
  import WebKit

  class ViewController: NSViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var searchTextField: NSTextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var browserWebView: WKWebView!
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      browserWebView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
      searchTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
      let StringURL:String = "https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=ピザ+inurl:/recipe/+site:cookpad.com"
      let url = URL(string:StringURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!)
      let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
      self.browserWebView.load(urlRequest)

  }
  override var representedObject: Any? {
      didSet {
      }
  }
  }
  ```

### Problem

- GoogleChromeでは料理の画像が表示されるのですが、WebKitでは表示されません(下記画像参照)。

  - GoogleChrome
    [image: GoogleChrome]
  - WebKit(Xcode Simulatror)
    [image: WebKit(Xcode Simulatror)]

### Question

- WebKitで検索した際に画像を表示する方法はありますか？

### Development Environment

- Swift3

### Tried → Error

- Tried : WebKitで検索する際に検索タブを "すべて" ではなく "画像" にする。
  →Error : 画像は表示されますが人気順ではなくなってしまう他、テキストも少なくなってしまう。
- Tried : JavaScriptを無効にしたGoogle ChromeのビューはWebKit（Xcode Simulator）と同じ結果だったので以下のコードを追加した。

  ```
  let preferences = WKPreferences()
  preferences.javaScriptEnabled = false

  let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
  configuration.preferences = preferences
  ```

  →Error : そもそもデフォルトのWebKitではJavaScriptが有効になっているため、この方法では問題は解決しない。

Comment: ヒント: ユーザーエージェント

Comment: @hinaloe さん　ヒントありがとうございます！！customUserAgentで解決できました！！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

この問題を解決するために、viewDidLoad（）にcustomUserAgentを追加しました。

```
browserWebView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36”
```

- WebKit(Xcode Simulatror)
  [image: CookingLog_customUserAgent]